# Java Non-blocking IO CPU Leak

Tags: java, asynchronous, cpu, nio, memory-leaks

I written simple NIO server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(65536);
    Selector selector = Selector.open();
    ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    server.configureBlocking(false);
    server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(724));
    server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    while(server.isOpen())
    {
        selector.selectNow();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
            if(!key.isValid())
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid key removed!");
                key.channel().close();
                key.cancel();
                continue;
            }
            if(key.isAcceptable())
            {
                server.accept().configureBlocking(false).register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                System.out.println("Accepting channel...");
                continue;
            }
            if(key.isReadable())
            {
                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                try
                {
                    channel.read((ByteBuffer) buffer.clear());
                    if(buffer.flip().limit() == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println(buffer.get() & 0xFF);
                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    channel.close();
                    key.cancel();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it's client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    try(Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 724))
    {
        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        output.write(15);
        output.flush();
    }
}
```

Once the client is disconnected from the server, the load on the CPU increases up to 40%
[image]

I tried to find a solution, but the search has given nothing.
I think this is due to the fact that the selector does not remove disconnect the client, but I do not know how to test - whether the client is disconnected or not. channel.isOpen() always returns true.

Comment: Have you tried profiling with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)? That might tell you exactly where the system is spending its time.

Comment: EDIT: Most CPU time is spent by java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int);

Comment: You don't need to cancel the key if you have just closed the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc for Selector.selectNow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#selectNow%28%29)

> This method performs a non-blocking selection operation. If no channels have become selectable since the previous selection operation then this method immediately returns zero.

Yes, that's going to burn CPU; it's non-blocking and you have a tight loop.

**Edit to add:** Generally the idea behind using a `Selector` is that you use the blocking `select()` or `select(long timeout)` versions which means as soon as a socket does something, it unblocks.

Comment: Same happens with Selector.select().

Comment: I tested both Selector.select() and Selector.select(timeout), same result.

Comment: Tested them where? What did you do differently? Using `select()` would require a good bit of change in your code.

Comment: Can you show how to do it? I have no idea how to do it differently

Comment: @user1936245 If you don't know how to do it why did you say you had done it? Or, if you have already done it, why are you saying you don't know how to do it?

Comment: I mean how to do it DIFFERENTLY. @chrylis said that in order to make this code works with select(), i need to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. I forgot close connection after EOS received.

```
if(channel.read((ByteBuffer) buffer.clear()) == -1)
{
    channel.close();
    continue;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't close the connection. It just cancels the key. You are correct that you should close the connection on EOS but you aren't doing it.

Comment: I repeat. You don't need to cancel the key after you close the channel. Fixed it for you.